# How to get Mongodb collection data from a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, activerecord, yii2

In Yii2, I try to get another field data (which inside a Mongo collection) from a table (DB activerecord) in MySQL table.

My `summary` table/model looks like this.

```
'merchant_id'       => '123'
'report_date'       => '2023-02-22'
'total_transaction' => 91
'total_amount'      => 998471
```

My `merchant` collection in Mongo looks like this (with the `merchant_id` as a "foreign key")

```
merchant_id => '123',
name        => 'Merchant A',
branch_code => '123',
type        => 'Type A'
```

I need to display the complete data with a `GridView`, with all filter and sort, etc. For example, if a "merchant_type" filter is set, then the GridView should show only relevant rows.

I include what I tried on the answer. It probably has a way better approach.

Comment: In general, you can't design NoSQL models optimally until you know the _specific_ queries they will serve.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes, you have a very good point. In my answer below, I 'wait' for all queries and then search the collection based on that. I am not prepared to this kind of scheme. What is your suggestion?

Comment: What about declaring the merchant relation in summary model? Since the `yii2-mongodb` package defines its own implementation of `ActiveRecord` and `ActiveQuery` Yii should be fine with both models being stored in different DBs. At least as long as you won't try using `joinWith()` with that relation. In `GridView` you can access properties of related model simply as `merchant.branch_code`. And declaring it as relation should allow you to use eager loading to avoid N+1 selects problem. You will just have to deal with sorting/filtering yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if it's ideal, but the DB scheme is weird already.

I make a "getMerchant()" in Summary model

```php
public function getMerchant()
{
    $merchant = Merchant::find()->where(['merchant_id' => $this->merchant_id])->one();
    
    return $merchant;
}
```

... and get all merchant IDs from merchant collection based on the filter

```php
public function getMerchantIDs($where = []) 
{
    $merchant_ids = Merchant::find()->
        select('merchant_id')->
        where($where)->
        column();
    
    return $merchant_ids;
}
```

And for the search model,

```
public $merchant_type;
public $merchant_branch_code;

public function search($params) {
    .......
    .......
    $condition = [];
    if (isset($this->merchant_type)) {
        $condition['merchant_type'] = $this->merchant_type;
    }

    if (isset($this->merchant_branch_code)) {
        $condition['branch_code'] = $this->merchant_branch_code;
    }

    $merchant_ids = $this->getMerchantIDs($condition);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'merchant_id', $merchant_ids]);
```

On GridView, something like this :

```
[
    'attribute' => 'merchant_branch_code',
    'label' => 'Branch Code',
    'value' => function($model){
        return $model->merchant->branch_code;
    },
],
```